# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter' in your configuration

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement the auditing part for our project persistence layer by adding these below Annotation (

1. @CreatedDate
2. @ModifyDate
3. @CreatedBy
4. @ModifiedBy

The last step is to add `@EnableMongoAuditing` to the MainClass

```
import com.ptc.swat.springmvc.domain.common.model.ExcludedUnitTestGeneratedReport;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;

@ExcludedUnitTestGeneratedReport
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class UserApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Everything seems to find until I try to clean and build my project and facing the below error
[image]

and this

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoAuditingHandler'
```

What should I do now? I've performed some research however, I cannot find the solution for this issue. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a class as below explicitly

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration
```